# I could tell you some war stories

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My bark is worse than a bite from me.
Cleopatra has nothing to do with me!

Some say I'm from Germany, maybe they know.
Some say I'm from England, A+ if it's so.

Some say that I'm crapulous, a literal shame.
Look thrice to the heavens and tell me my name.

Hint

> I am the lesser (and the greater) of two evils.

Hint #2

> I am *neither* a historic, giant adversary, *nor* am I a rhinoceros. Or am i?

Hint #3

> This puzzle was created under Puzzling License # LMW-28IF

Comment: the last sentence tells me that this thing is some sort of deity or they're dead... that's my only guess i can't see much else lol

Comment: I tried, I can't get anywhere with this. The two middle lines have baffled me.

Comment: I'm trying to formulate an answer with rot13(terlubhaq), is it related?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel terlubhaq + the wrong tree = bark. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm riding on the coattails of Mick O'Hea here. You are ...

> ... a **beetle**.

My bark is worse than a bite from me.

> An allusion to bark beetles. Some beetles bite, but their bite isn't dangerous.

Cleopatra has nothing to do with me!

> Beetles are of the order [Coleoptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle), which sounds like – but has nothing to do with – Cleopatra.

Some say I'm from Germany, maybe they know.

> The [Volkswagen Beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Beetle) is a classic car from Germany.

Some say I'm from England, A+ if it's so.

> [The Beatles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles) are from England. The "A+" indicates that they are written with an a, I guess.

Some say that I'm crapulous, a literal shame.

> An allusion to dung beeltes. "Crapulous" is related to drink, though, not to crap, and it's a "literal shame" to confuse the two (OP).

Look thrice to the heavens and tell me my name.

> In a film from 1988, the ghost Betelgeuse can be summoned by calling his name three times. The name sounds like [Beetlejuice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetlejuice), which is also the name of the film (OP).

Hint: I am the lesser (and the greater) of two evils.

> A pun on "the lesser and the greater of two weevils" (from OP).

Hint #2: I am neither a historic, giant adversary, nor am I a rhinoceros. Or am i?

> No, you are not, but there are [Goliath beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliathus) and [rhinoceros beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynastinae).

Hint #3: This puzzle was created under Puzzling License # LMW-28IF

> Mick O'Hea found out that this is the licence number of a VW Beetle on the cover of The Beatles' Abbey Road album.

Title: I could tell you some war stories

> [Beeltle Bailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle_Bailey) is a long-running cartoon about life in an army camp (OP).

Comment: +1 for a) Giving @MickO'Hea a chance to revise, and b) Answering correctly, eventually, anyways! I'll give it a little while before ☑ing the ☑.

Comment: As for the last lines and hints that you weren't sure of: rot13 (Vg'f n "yvgreny" funzr gung fbzr crbcyr jbhyq hfr "penchybhf" va qrfpevovat n qhat orrgyr. Urnirayl obql:Orgrytrhfr, Va na 80'f zbivr, gurl fnvq 3 × "OrrgyrWhvpr!" Byq wbxr: [gjb jrrivyf](uggcf://jjj.lbhghor.pbz/jngpu?i=r4CmckBw5Pp). Gvgyr: [Orrgyr Onvyrl](uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Orrgyr_Onvyrl) pnegbba fgevc.)

Comment: Haha! Well done! I wouldn't have got it, I was looking too deep

Answer (score 6):

Could you be...

> Superman? I don't have an answer for every line, but I'm not a comic geek.

I could tell you some war stories

> [War of the worlds?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_War_of_the_Worlds)

Cleopatra has nothing to do with me!

> Cleopatra is in the Marvel Universe, while Superman is in DC.

Some say I'm from Germany, maybe they know.

> [Übermensch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbermensch), literally German for Superman.

Look thrice into the heavens and tell me my name.

> It's a bird! It's a plane! No, it's Superman!

Comment: For the first line: he owns a dog named Krypto (dunno how well that fits, though).

Comment: I was wondering what Cleopatra had (not) to do with it... I'm not big into comics either. I believe that the correct answer will be more convincing as it pertains to each line.

Comment: @Chowzen It fit the last line so well, I thought it must be it. Oh well :)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answers (mainly for the hints)

I've a gut feeling it's something to do with some kind of

> weapon, possibly a tank, probably from WWII. The war stories, Germany and England references, hint this way. Bark worse than bite implies something loud but not very deadly. Cleopatra suggests Asp or Needle.

Hint 2

> Goliath and Rhino both sound like good tank names. I can't find anything that specifically matches - there was a WWII APC called a Rhino and a German tracked vehicle called a Goliath. So maybe something in the same family?

Hint 3

> Apparently LMW 28IF is the license plate on a Volkswagen Beetle on the Beatles  Abbey Road album cover. So again, a German vehicle

But I can't put it all together

Comment: These are excellent thoughts. There are bark and dung beetles; the VW Beetle is from Germany; the Beatles ("A+") are from England. And if you search for "Cleopatra beetle", Google's autocorrect may have a surprise in store for you. `:)`